# How to show particular purchase order total price in my custom module for that particular purchase order in OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

How to show particular purchase order total price in my custom module 
I am creating a function for show amount_total in my custom module but it's not showing

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    if vals.get('buy_back'):
        purchase_obj=self.pool.get('purchase.order')
        sequence=self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'purchase.order')
        new_purchase=purchase_obj.create(cr, uid, {'name':sequence,'amt_total':vals.get('amount_total')}, context=context)
        import pprint
        pprint.pprint( vals )
        print 'amount_total'
        vals['purchase_order']=new_purchase
        pprint.pprint( vals )
```

This is my view file

```
                    <field name="buy_back"/>
                    <field name="purchase_order"/>
                    <fiels name="amt_total"/>
                </xpath>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a related field of amount_total of purchase order to show the amount_total.

Like:

when you create field

then you can make a related field like:

```
 'amt_total': fields.related('purchase_order', 'amount_total', type='float', string='Amount Total', store=True),
```

And show this field.

Hope this help

Comment: thank but it's not showing any result it's not show on my view

Comment: in related field when purchase_order assign i will automatically show to attached purchase_order total in amount_toal field

Comment: it's not occur in my view so please tell me what i do now

Comment: now i want to subtract amt_total from the amount_total so how can i do that. Is here i have to override _amount_all method or something else

Comment: I am not getting your point? why you want to subtract amt_total from amount_total?

Comment: actually i want generate purchase order and purchase order amount subtract from sale order amount and also customized invoice report for both amt_total and total amount so how  can i do this and now i am able to subtract bt now i am working on invoicing

Comment: your requirement in too confused me, how suddenly came here sale order amount_toal? give me your requirement i will do this for you.